# How to resolve the CORS issue using proxy in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am using express Node backend and frontend for angular. the thing is when i was integrate my API to angular i had CORS problem. inside the developer console i have got a error like this "XmlHttpRequet cannot load http://localhost:3000/student No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

I have tried to proxy the backend adding a proxy-confg.json inside the angular project. but the result also same. still have CORS problem.

```
// node js endpoint
ApienpointUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/stdApi/student';

// getting data from endpoint
getStudentfromMock() {
return this.http.get(this.ApienpointUrl).pipe(
  map((res: any) => res),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}
```

Here the Proxy configuration inside angular project proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/stdApi/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

i am getting error like this:-

```
"XmlHttpRequet cannot load http://localhost:4200/stdApi/student No Access-Control-Allow-Origin. header is present on the request resources origin 'http://localhost:3000' therefor not allowed access".
```

Comment: Verify well the Api Endpoint url , maybe you have more prefixes (like stdApi/v1 ), as a suggestion, verify the apiEndpoint in your environement.ts : instead of 'localhost:3000' is should be 'localhost:3000/stdApi'   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in app.js file.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   // Website you wish to allow to connect
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   // Request methods you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, token, language');

   // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
   // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

   // Pass to next layer of middleware
   next(); 
});
```

And restart the server.

Comment: Bypassing CORS will be a security threat. 
You can read more here: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors#:~:targetText=Why%20is%20CORS%20necessary%3F,the%20standard%20HTTP%20request%20methods.
Angular always recommends using proxy server for avoiding CORS issue on development.

Comment: How to pass API Key in the header?

Comment: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` Browsers no longer accept `*` as a valid Origin since 2018

Answer (score 2):

For proxying to backend server, after adding proxy configuration in `proxy.conf.json` in your project's `src/` folder, add the `proxyConfig` option to the `serve` target, in the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

Then run dev server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

**OR**

Run `ng serve` with proxy configuration:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

More info: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: Thanks mate. Yes you are right. but i have just modify the package.json and run the project using npm start. this is also work well.

"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "client": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
}

Comment: Yeah. You can do it with `scripts` property in `package.json` too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to fix this CORS. here what it is.

**Rewriting the URL path**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

This also work for me.

Comment: This is were i have found the answare. [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: The link you provided is broken. Can you update it?