# How to correct a problem related to the Cors Origin in spring boot with angular 11?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a problem with my API which I developed in Spring boot and Angular. when I try to record a new performance with an image I always have the same error linked to the Cors cross origin headers.

Here is my controller and the method used to create a Prestation

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/prestations")
public class PrestationController {

    private byte[] bytes;
    @Autowired
    IPrestationService prestationService;
    @Autowired
    PrestationRepository prestationRepository;
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;


@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> savePrestaWithImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("prestation")String prestation)
    throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, Exception {
        Prestation presta = new ObjectMapper().readValue(prestation, Prestation.class);
        boolean isExist = new File(context.getRealPath("/Images/")).exists();
        if(!isExist){
            new File(context.getRealPath("/Images/")).mkdir();
            System.out.println("dossier créer");
        }
        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename(); // je recupere le nom de l'image
        String newFileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filename)+"."+FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);
        File serverFile = new File(context.getRealPath("/Images/"+File.separator+newFileName));
        try {
            System.out.println("Image");
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(serverFile, file.getBytes());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        presta.setPhoto(newFileName);
        Prestation prestation1 = prestationRepository.save(presta);
        if(prestation1 != null){
            return new ResponseEntity<MessageResponse>(new MessageResponse(""), HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            return  new ResponseEntity<MessageResponse>(new MessageResponse("Prestation not saved"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
```

**Here is my angular service**

```
savePrestation(prestation: Prestation): Observable<Prestation> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-type ': 'application/json',
        'Acces-Control-Allow-Origin': '/*'
      })
    }
    return this.http.post<Prestation>(this.SAVE_PRESTA, prestation, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`save prestation with id = ${prestation.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('addPresta'))
    );
  }
```

**here is my angular method savePresta**

```
savePresta() {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('imageFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.selectedFile.imageName = this.selectedFile.name;

    this.http.post(this.SAVE_PRESTA + '/upload', uploadData, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.service.savePrestation(this.prestation).subscribe(
            (prestation) => {
              this.prestation = prestation;
              this.goBack();
            });
          console.log('image uploaded successfull');
        } else {
          console.log('image not uploaded sucessfull')
        }
      });
  }
```

I still have the same error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/prestations' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
POST http://localhost:8080/prestations net::ERR_FAILED

ERROR HttpErrorResponse headers: HttpHeaders status: 0 statusText: "Unknown Error" url:"http://localhost:8080/prestations", ok: false …

help me please that days that I block the top I tried everything but nothing helped
```

Comment: I don't think you should be passing 'Acces-Control-Allow-Origin': '/*' into the POST, but that's probably not the main problem.

Comment: yes Michael you are right I put it by despair hoping that it would work.

Answer (score 2):

It is a CORS problem, related to a security issue.

**The problem**

Suppose that your frontend is hosted on `xxx.com` and the backend is on `yyy.com`.

From the browser point of view, you are connected to `xxx.com` but issue requests to `yyy.com`, which is weird. If `yyy.com` does not explicitly authorizes to send request from `xxx.com`, the browser will block the request.

Now, how does the browser knows that `yyy.com` authorizes requests from `xxx.com` ? With a pre-flight request. The browser executes a pre-flight request and expect to find some CORS related HTTP headers in the response. See ? This is what is written in the error message: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check`

Here is an example of such HTTP headers  :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://toto.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Here, `localhost:4200` and `localhost:8080` are considered as 2 different origins

**What can you do ?**

You have 2 solutions :  create a proxy OR set correct HTTP headers

**Create a proxy**

Suppose that you create a proxy on `zzz.com`. Your browser is connected to `zzz.com`, and all backend calls are made to `zzz.com`. From your browser point of view, there are no more cross origin resources sharing.

But, `zzz.com` has to redirect frontend requests to `xxx.com` and backend requests to `yyy.com`. This can easily be done if you decide that all your backend requests start with something like `/api`. This will allow you to write a simple regex :

- starts with `/api` => backend
- else => frontend

Fortunately, in dev environment, Angular provides a built-in solution for that. You can take a look at [Proxying to a backend server](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)
It merely consist of starting the angular app with the `--proxy-config` option pointing to a file such as :

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

(Here, we suppose that all your backend endpoints start with `/api`)

**HTTP Headers**

This answer provides a solution with some Angular conf : [How to resolve the CORS issue using proxy in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814961/how-to-resolve-the-cors-issue-using-proxy-in-angular)

**Never** ever use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

If you want to easily modify HTTP Headers for test purposes, you can install the Chrome extension `modHeader`

**Note** : you will have exactly this problem when you go to production so the solution choice must be driven by the solution you need in production.

Comment: Thank you Arnould for your message. I tried your solution but I still have the same error. I add the proxy and modify the url but nothing changes.

Comment: @Diallosouleymane did you start the app with the `--proxy-config` option ? Also, you should now issue the backend requests to `localhost:4200` and let the proxy redirect them to `localhost:8080`. Look at your browser debugging tools, you should see requests to `localhost:4200`

Answer (score 0):

I am using very simple solution to develop Spring Web Services when dealing with cors:

1. Call cors() method in SpringSecurityConfig to configure cors. Because Spring Security process request before it reaches Controller:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // other configs ...
        http.cors();
        // other configs ...
```

2. In every controller i use annotation @CrossOrigin

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class EventController extends BaseController {
}
```

However maybe it is possible to simplify if moving @CrossOrigin to BaseController will work (i have not checked it).

Comment: Thanks for your return. but I have already tried this solution but nothing changes.